# Thread-safe C++ wrapper around a lex/yacc parser

Tags: c++, yacc, lex

I am trying to write a JSON parser (instead of using one of the freely available ones, because of certain project constraints) and have written lex+yacc based version with a simple wrapper C++ class. I have redefined the YY_INPUT macro for lex to read from a memory buffer. Now the deal is to ensure that the parser is thread-safe and I am not sure how easy it is to ensure that. There are two concerns:

1. Ultimately YY_INPUT is reading from a global object. I could not think of another way of doing this.
2. I have no idea how many globals does the generated lex/yacc code end up using.

Would be great if folks can share their experience of doing something similar.

Cheers.

PS. We don' t use STL/string or any templates for that matter. We use our own variant-based containers. We use lex+yacc rather than flex+bison, on four major Unices.

Comment: Thread-safe and re-entrant are two different beasts. Changed the title to use the correct term.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have much experience working directly with `yacc`, but I know that `bison` supports [reentrant parsers](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Decl) that are thread-safe.  It also looks like [`lex` supports a reentrant lexer as well](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant.html), and I'd guess that if you put the two together it should work out just fine.